# How can I use a JVM program on a cluster? (Like the discontinued cJVM/JavaSplit)

Tags: java, linux, multithreading, jvm, cluster-computing

I've been digging into the depths of IBM's research on [JavaSplit](https://www.research.ibm.com/haifa/Workshops/compiler2003/papers/IBMJavaSplitPresentation_ver4_no_comments.pdf) and [cJVM](https://www.research.ibm.com/haifa/projects/systems/cjvm/) because I want to run a JVM program across a cluster of 4 Raspberry Pi 3 Model B's like [This](http://makezine.com/projects/build-a-compact-4-node-raspberry-pi-cluster/).

I know nearly nothing about clusters and distributed computing, so I'm starting my dive into the depths by trying to get a Minecraft Server running across them.

My question is, is there a relatively simply way to get a Java program running on a JVM to split across a cluster without source code access?

**Notes:**

The main problem is that most java programs (toy program included) were not built to run across a cluster, but I'm hoping that I can find a method to hack the JVM to have it work.

I've seen some possible solutions but due to the nature of Minecraft and Java, updates come so frequently and the landscape changes that I don't even know what is possible.

As far as I know, [FastCraft](https://minecraft.curseforge.com/projects/fastcraft) implements multithreading support, or it used to and it's now built in.

**Purpose:**

This is a both a toy program and a practical problem for me. I'm doing it to learn how clusters work, to learn more about Linux administration and distributed computing, and because it's fun. I'm not doing it to setup a minecraft server. The server is a cherry on top, but if it doesn't work out I'll shove it on a Dell tower.

Comment: Clustering is usually accomplished by modifying the program.

Comment: @meriton There are frameworks to do this for the program in question, such as http://files.minecraftforge.net/, and https://www.spigotmc.org/, but I've no idea if any are powerful enough.

I'm mostly looking to be pointed in the right direction by someone who's done clustering.

Comment: @meriton In the end though, minecraft is my "example", a toy program to learn how to scale other applications.

Comment: I wouldn't call a game engine a toy...

Answer (score 1):

MineCraft can be scaled using what is effectively a partitioning service. The tool which is usually used is [BungeeCord](https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/bungeecord/) This allows a client to connect to a service which passes the session to multiple backend servers which run largely without change. This limits the number of users which can be in one server, but between them you can have any number of servers.

Comment: I'd like a more general solution, as minecraft is just a toy program for this usecase. It's my "example".

Comment: @NictraSavios the problem you have is that minecraft has a single core thead due to the way it is written. This means of you have Quad core ARM processor, it won't even use half the processing power you have in one machine. Say you had a more general solution (which are not so popular because they are usually orders of magnitude  slower) it would still be single threaded at its core. The only way to make it even suitable for more CPU is to re write the core engine, or you could use a faster processor and/or use bungeecord.

Answer (score 0):

I can only reiterate that such a generic solution, if one exists, is not commonly applied. There are inherent challenges to try and distribute a JVM, such as translating a shared memory execution model, where all memory access is cheap, to a distributed model, where non-local memory access is orders of magnitude more expensive, without degrading performance. This requires smart partitioning of data, and finding such partitions in an automated way is a very complex optimization problem.

In the particular example of minecraft, one would additionally have to transform a single threaded program into a multi threaded one, which is a rather complex program transformation by itself.

In a nutshell, solving the clustering problem in such generality is a research level topic, for which, to the best of my knowledge, no algorithms competitive with manual code changes currently exist. In addition, if such an algorithm were to exist, if would be very unlikely to be offered free of charge, because it would represent both a significant achievement, and could be licensed for a lot of money.